# Stuck with I/O operations in lua

Tags: lua, file-handling

I'm trying to design a game in lua (This is my first game since I'm new to this language)
Okay.. So I have run a score counter that adds up +1 on screen tap.
What I want to do is I want to save the high score permanently.

I want to display the high score ('30' in this case) separately on the screen. And this is where I'm stuck.
I tried tweaking with the I/O library, but this made things go more complicated.
Can anyone help me with this please?

This is what I have tried:

```
local f1 = io.open ("scoredata.txt", "a")

function gameOver()  
disp_tempscore()

if score>highScore    -- Here initial value of highScore was 0
    then
    highScore=score
io.write (highScore)
end  

score=0     -- This turns the score 0. (There is a separate score counter that counts the score and stores in 'score')

mainScreen()
local f2 = io.open ("scoredata.txt", "r")
if f2~= nil
then
save_high = io.read(highScore)

end
    text_display2= display.newText("BEST : " .. highScore, 0, 0, "Helvetica", 90)
    text_display2.x = centerX
    text_display2.y = centerY + 80
    text_display2.alpha=1
```

Now here the score for 'BEST :' appears the highest score, BUT only for multiple runs at same time.
What I mean to say is  when I start the game in corona simulator and play the game for 5 times (suppose), then highest score shows correct data.
But, when I exit simulator and restart it, the highest score vanishes and displays 0.
How can I store the data (score in this case) permanently?

EDIT: (This is what I had tried last (one of the hits I tried))

```
local function disapp (event)                   -- An event listener that responds to "tap"

local obj = event.target
display.remove (obj)

audio.play(sound)

transition.cancel (event.target.trans)

score=score+1
curr_scoreDisp = score
scoreText.text=score

local f1 = io.open (path, "a")   --Writing score to file
if score>highScore  -- Initial value of highScore is 0
    then
    highScore=score
    f1:write(highScore)
end
io.close(f1)
```

Then :

```
local function disp_Permscore()
local f1 = io.open (path, "r")

f1:read(highScore)
    text_display2= display.newText("BEST : " .. highScore, 0, 0, "Helvetica", 90)
    text_display2.x = centerX
    text_display2.y = centerY + 80
    text_display2.alpha=1 
    io.close(f1)
end
```

This is another function that reads score from file and then displays it.
Now? Does this help in rectifying the problem in any way?

Comment: I'm sure many would like to help but must provide more information. Show the code you are using (only the portion related to your question of course), and describe what is wrong, for example the output is different from what you expect.

Comment: I hope the code I provided helps you understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you never write to the score file:

```
io.write (highScore)
```

should be

```
f1:write(highScore)
```

and you should close the file as soon as you no longer need it (will prevent loss of data due to a crash, e.g.). Also don't forget to use `system.pathForFile( filename, system.DocumentsDirectory)` as described in Corona docs, so the file is put in the correct location.

Comment: Okay.. I did as you said.

Comment: I did as you said. But I'm still facing the same problem. 
Again the 'BEST:' shows 0 when I again run the simulator after exiting it once.

Comment: Please see the EDIT above. This is what I tried last.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `file:read()` function incorrectly. It takes an 'option' argument and returns what it read. Thus,

```
f1:read(highScore)
```

should be

```
highScore = f1:read("*n")
```

where the `"*n"` argument specifies you want to read a number.

**Edit:**

To prevent trouble with files not being written/read properly, try the following (untested) code:

```
if score > highScore then
    highScore = score
    local f1 = io.open(path, "w") -- opening in write mode erases content
    f1:write(highScore)           -- write the new highscore
    f1:close()                    -- close the file
end
```

for writing, and

```
local f1 = io.open(path, "r")     -- open the file in read mode
highScore = f1:read("*n")         -- read the saved highscore

if highScore == nil then          -- if the highscore could not be read
    --error code here (e.g. set highscore to 0, notify the user, etc.)
end

f1:close()                        -- close the file
```

for reading.

Comment: It didn't work either. I got output like - "7.11428... +079"
Though the actual score is 3

Comment: Are you sure the file is empty when you start or that there are whitespaces between different records? When reading a number, `f1:read()` will try to match the biggest number it can find, so if you have printed several numbers it will indeed turn out to be a really big number.

Comment: I think it worked for a moment. I deleted all the files in directory to start from fresh. Since I had opened file in append mode, the score was being written after the old score.. So I changed it to write mode. 
Now another problem rises :|
Now, when I run the program and score more than highscore, it gets saved in the file (permanently).. But, when I score less than highscore, it pops up an error saying "attempt to concatenate upvalue highscore(a nil value)"
I tried various combinations.. One of them eliminated the error.. but then again data could not be stored permanently :|

Comment: What might happen is that when you open the file in write mode, the previous content of the file is deleted. If then the score appears to be lower than the highscore, the file will be closed without anything being written to it. This in turn will result in the read function to read nothing, and thus it returns nil. You should fix this in both the write and read functions. For the read function, I suggest `highScore = f1:read("*n") or 0`. This will give highScore a default value of 0 if the highscore cannot be read from the file.

Comment: Okay.. I did this too. Now when I score less than highscore, highscore becomes 0. Means when I score less than highscore, the "BEST:" on display screen shows 0

Comment: A small edit I did just now :

    `local function write_score()

 
    if score>highScore

    then

    local f1 = io.open (path, "w")

    highScore=score
    f1:write(highScore)
    io.close(f1)
    end

    end`

It has now eliminated the error I was getting earlier, but now again   the data gets truncated when I restart the simulator :|

Comment: What exactly do you mean by truncated? See the edit I just posted for a (possible) fix for the read function.

Comment: Yeah I edited the read function as you suggested. By truncated I mean that when I close the simulator, highScore becomes 0 again instead of holding "highscore" data.

Comment: Could you open the file once the program has closed? That way you can determine where the error is: in the read or in the write code. Also, you might try to add `f1:flush()` between the write and close function.

Comment: `f1:flush` did not work even.. Everytime I re-run the simulator, the value of "highScore" becomes 0 [It should be holding the game highscore though]. That is the issue the issue. (Because when I write data to file in append mode[like after restarting the simulator], it shows previous data too).